# Как проверить строку на наличие недопустимых символов?

Tags: java

Нужно сделать проверку строки, чтобы пропускало только латиницу [a-z].
Всё что не попадает в этот список пропускаться не должно.
Так же если пользователь ввёл символы верхнего регистра, они должны быть трансформированы в символы нижнего регистра.
Есть у кого простые решения данной задачи? В голову лезет только проверка каждого символа через цикл. Но даже тут не понятно как это правильно написать.

```
for(int i = 0; i < login.length(); i++){

           if(login.charAt(i) //тут хочу .matches влепить, но не работает так. :(((
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переводим в нижний регистр:

```
String lowerInput = inputString.toLowerCase();
```

Проверяем на наличие только допустимых символов:

```
if (lowerInput.matches("[a-z]+"))
{
    // делаем что хотим
};
```

Регулярное выражение `[a-z]+` задает правило, что строка должна состоять из одного или более символов (это задается знаком `+`), входящих в диапазон от `а` до `z`.

Comment: Но ведь оно ничего не проверяет. Если написать в строку abc&*((^ то его спокойно пропустит, т.к. есть символы abc в строке. А мне нужно все запрещённые символы отбросить

Comment: Регулярное выражение ничего не проверяет, оно только задает правило. Проверяет метод ``str.matches()``. Если ``str`` удовлетворяет правилу, то результат ``true``, если не удовлетворяет, то ``false``.

Comment: @Kermach, вы бы попробовали сперва, прежде чем утверждать :)

Comment: Т.к. символы &*((^ не входят в диапазон a-z, то результат проверки будет отрицательным, если проверяемой строке будет хотя бы один из этих символов.